# Django Rest Framework use source to access different model with reverse relation?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following problem, I have the default User model and Profile model. I want to merge them into one serializer but without nesting - It's just ugly. Instead, I want to have all their fields on the first level. So I created the following (for simplicity profile contains just one Bool field and one relation field):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    achievements = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelated(many=True, queryset=Achievements.objects.all())
    trusted = serializers.BooleanField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user=User.objects.create_user(
            password = validated_data['password'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
        )

        Profile.objects.update_or_create(user, defaults={
            'trusted': validated_data['trusted'],
            'achievements': validatd_data['achievements'],
            }
        )
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "username", "email", "password", "trusted", "achievements"),
        read_only = ("id",)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
            },
        }
```

Profile is connected to a user via a user field containing `models.OneToOneField` instance.

When I try to list all profiles I get Error that I need to specify `source` but I have no idea how and documentation mentions only something that dot notation should be used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`source` is argument of serializer field. You should do something like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    achievements = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelated(many=True, queryset=Achievements.objects.all(), source='profile.achievements')
    trusted = serializers.BooleanField(source='profile.trusted')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user=User.objects.create_user(
            password = validated_data['password'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            email = validated_data['email'],
        )

        Profile.objects.update_or_create(user, defaults={
            'trusted': validated_data['trusted'],
            'achievements': validatd_data['achievements'],
            }
        )
        return user
```

Comment: Yes, but since User has no field named profile he throws an exception.

Comment: @JanKaifer did you add to profile model onetoonefield with user?

Comment: Anyway I have solved it by going from the other end - extending ProfileSerializer which has user field